# Input field value and redirect using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little problem with my contact form and jquery redirection based on input fields.

Everything was perfect until I tried to implement redirection to form validation code.

Redirection code:

```
$("#signup").submit(function(event){
    window.location = $('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
});
```

Form:

```
<form id="signup" name="signup" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">

<input type="radio" name="gender" value="http://www.paypal.com" checked> Option 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="http://www.google.com"> Option 2<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="http://www.seznam.cz"> Option 3<br>

<input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Continue to make payment..." class="btn btn-wide btn-extrawide" data-loading-text="Loading...">
```

jQuery:

```
// Signup form
$('#signup').validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        name: {
            required: "Please enter your nameee",
            minlength: "Your name must consist of at least 2 characters"
        },
        email: {
            required: "Please enter your email address"
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $(form).ajaxSubmit({
            type:"POST",
            data: $(form).serialize(),
            url:"inc/signup.php",
            success: function() {
                $('#signup :input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $('#signup').fadeTo( "slow", 0.15, function() {
                    $(this).find(':input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $(this).find('label').css('cursor','default');
                    $('#success').fadeIn();
                });

                    // added lines, not working:                    
                    $("#signup").submit(function(event) {
                        window.location = $('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
                    });


            },
            error: function() {
                $('#signup').fadeTo( "slow", 0.15, function() {
                    $('#error').fadeIn();
                });
            }

        });
    }
});
```

Will be happy for any feedback you can give me. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Adam, what is the problem here? Please specify problem statement

Comment: use `window.location.href` instead of `window.location`

Comment: yes, use `window.location.href`.

Comment: No, that's wrong.  assigning to `location` is synonymous with assigning to `location.href`.  See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are submitting the form again with your added lines:

```
// added lines, not working:                    
$("#signup").submit(function(event) {
    window.location = $('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
});
```

So after the ajax submit it does nothing because when you do the `$("#signup").submit` it didn't do anything due to the submit button being  disabled with this code:

`$('#signup :input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');`.

So to fix that, change the added code above from this:

```
$("#signup").submit(function(event) {
    window.location = $('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
});
```

To this:

```
window.location.href = $('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
```

Comment: Working like a charm! Thanks Robin.

Comment: @Adam Great! Glad it helped.